# Batch script query

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script, (only specifically batch script), to check if the latest Microsoft Office version is installed to my computer. If it detects the latest version, it will output `hello`, else it will output `heyo`.

However, it is not working. Appreciate all the help I can get!

```bash
reg query "HKEY_LOCALMACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" /v VersionToReport

IF "VersionToReport" EQU "16.0.10396.20023" GOTO hello ELSE GOTO heyo

:hello
echo hello

:heyo
echo heyo
```

Comment: If you want to perform an `if` comparison with the result of another command, you'd need to capture the result of that command to use in that comparison. Your `reg` command only outputs one or more lines, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture reg query output with FOR /F like this:

```
@echo off

for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (
    'reg query "HKEY_LOCALMACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" /v VersionToReport'
) do (
   set "VersionToReport=%%~a"
) 

IF "%VersionToReport%" EQU "16.0.10396.20023" (
    echo hello
) else (
    echo heyo
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistant! However, despite having the correct version of outlook, I am still not getting the correct echo. Any idea where went wrong in the command executed below?

C:\Windows\System32>for /F "skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCALMACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" /v VersionToReport') do (set "VersionToReport=%~a" )
delims = " was unexpected at this time.

C:\Windows\System32>IF "" EQU "16.0.10396.20023" (echo hello )  else (echo heyo )
heyo

C:\Windows\System32>TIMEOUT -T -1

Comment: @JustinLee what happens when you set `echo % VersionToReport%` just before the `if`?

Comment: It shows: C:\Windows\System32>echo
ECHO is on.

Comment: Note that I removed the line echo off to test if the script works

Comment: And what is the output of `reg query "HKEY_LOCALMACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" /v VersionToReport` ? @JustinLee